# Can I display the classes of all data objects in my R global environment?

Tags: r, class

I would like to obtain the class information (e.g. dataframe, sf object, etc.) on all data objects in my global environment at once without having to run code like this:

```
class(data1)
class(data2)
class(data3)
```

and so on. I have tried `ls.str()` and while that does technically achieve the goal, it gives me far more information than I am wanting at a single time. I want to display only the class of each object that is in the global environment.

Comment: Do you mean this: `l <- mget(ls(), envir = globalenv());
lapply(l, \(x) class(x))`?

Comment: Or without the temp var: `sapply(mget(ls(envir= globalenv())), class)`

Comment: Note that `class()` for a given object can be a vector of values. An object doesn't necessarily have just once "class" string. For example `class(dplyr::tibble())`